# Access via URL instead IP address to local dockerized Django project

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I got a small Django project which runs within a docker container and is locally only (no need to expose it to the whole internet, just my office), but since it's a corporate project I want to give the persons who use it the possibility to access it using an URL (maybe something like "projectName.corporateWhereIWork.org") instead *host machine ip address:port*. Being honest, I have already read and search about terms like "reverse-proxy", "companion", "ACME", "DNS" but these are concepts that are very difficult for me to understand and I don't know how to configure *nginx* properly.

This is my nginx config file (see it's a very simple configuration):

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

upstream project {  
  ip_hash;
  server project:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://project/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

And my Django image entry point:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; python manage.py migrate; gunicorn project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Both containers expose to same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just for a handful of people working off the same machines, your easiest route is going to be editing the local hosts file on each machine. E.g. on Windows you can append an entry like `192.168.0.10 example.com` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and that machine will now resolve example.com to the given IP address.

If your requirements involve many people and machines then, unfortunately, you're going to have to get familiar with DNS.

But don't worry. For your stated purposes, you don't need to understand anything more complex than the very basic function of DNS--i.e. resolving a name to an IP address, as was done in the `hosts` example above.

The entry types you're interested in here are `A` (resolve a name to an IP) and `CNAME` (resolve a name to another name). E.g. you might set up an `A` record that resolves `example.com` to `192.168.0.10` and a `CNAME` record that resolves `www.example.com` to `example.com`. The latter would then resolve `www.example.com` to the IP address given for `example.com`.

How you actually set this up, however, will need some research from you. You may get lucky and have the functionality built into your office router, but don't count on it.